# How to debug slow server response time?

Tags: networking, performance, https, response-time

Using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22625150/2624391) to measure server response time, I can see that `time_appconnect`, `time_pretransfer`, and `time_starttransfer` are extremely high, but only when accessing the website through HTTPS.

For comparison, connecting to Google is very fast.

```
curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s "https://www.google.com"
```

returns

```
time_namelookup:     0.014433
time_connect:        0.117187
time_appconnect:     0.374567
time_pretransfer:    0.374779
time_redirect:       0.000000
time_starttransfer:  0.513398
                     ----------
        time_total:  0.514880
```

Connecting to our website through HTTP is also fairly fast:

```
curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s "http://environmentaldashboard.org"
```

returns

```
time_namelookup:    0.004136
time_connect:       0.044469
time_appconnect:    0.000000
time_pretransfer:   0.044554
time_redirect:      0.000000
time_starttransfer: 0.166275
                  ----------
      time_total:  0.166404
```

But connecting through HTTPS is *very* slow:

```
curl -w "@curl-format.txt" -o /dev/null -s "https://environmentaldashboard.org"
```

returns

```
time_namelookup:    0.005211
time_connect:       0.057697
time_appconnect:    11.931837
time_pretransfer:   11.932075
time_redirect:      0.000000
time_starttransfer: 11.972374
                  ----------
     time_total:  12.009711
```

---

How could this be? The issue started without any changes to code, as far as I can tell. I'm a fairly new sysadmin -- what tools can I use to debug this issue? Since the issue appears to be related to the SSL, is it possible that the problem is actually with our certificate authority (GoDaddy)? Or is the problem more likely a server misconfiguration?

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but this is the (slightly abbreviated) apache virtual host file for environmentaldashboard.org:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName environmentaldashboard.org
    ServerAlias www.environmentaldashboard.org
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/environmentaldashboard.org/environmentaldashboard.org.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/environmentaldashboard.org/environmentaldashboard.org.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/environmentaldashboard.org/intermediate.crt
    ServerAdmin dashboard@oberlin.edu
    DocumentRoot /var/www/environmentaldashboard.org/
    ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
    RewriteEngine On    
    <Directory /var/www/>
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
        RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName environmentaldashboard.org
    ServerAlias www.environmentaldashboard.org
    Redirect permanent / https://environmentaldashboard.org/
</VirtualHost>
```

#### EDIT

```
grep -Ev '(rv_cron|15min|PHP Warning)' /var/log/apache2/error.log | tail -n10000
```

returns this: https://pastebin.com/qZ5e5e1n

and

`journalctl -xef | grep -Ev '(rv_cron|15min|buildingosd)'`

returns this:

https://pastebin.com/DbUGFTmn

`top -d 30 | head -n50` returns:

```
top - 19:02:38 up  8:35,  1 user,  load average: 1.71, 1.98, 2.08
Tasks: 281 total,   1 running, 280 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 27.9 us,  3.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 55.1 id,  6.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.6 si,  5.0 st
KiB Mem :  4046472 total,  1300152 free,  1373280 used,  1373040 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.  2336100 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                
 8736 www-data  20   0  386056  22976  12248 S  55.6  0.6   0:06.03 apache2                                                                                                                                
15772 root      20   0  256696  81752   7072 S  22.2  2.0   1:34.52 buildingosd                                                                                                                            
14534 root      20   0  279284 104372   7104 S  16.7  2.6   2:04.70 buildingosd                                                                                                                            
19708 root      20   0   40680   3736   3116 R  16.7  0.1   0:00.05 top                                                                                                                                    
 1340 mysql     20   0 1583808 395376  18808 S   5.6  9.8  87:05.74 mysqld                                                                                                                                 
23451 www-data  20   0  384072  20896  12156 S   5.6  0.5   0:18.71 apache2                                                                                                                                
    1 root      20   0   37760   5756   3956 S   0.0  0.1   0:10.64 systemd                                                                                                                                
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 kthreadd                                                                                                                               
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:05.22 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                                                            
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H                                                                                                                           
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   3:30.70 rcu_sched                                                                                                                              
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh                                                                                                                                 
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.13 migration/0                                                                                                                            
   10 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.76 watchdog/0                                                                                                                             
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.91 watchdog/1                                                                                                                             
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.14 migration/1                                                                                                                            
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:13.13 ksoftirqd/1                                                                                                                            
   15 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H                                                                                                                           
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs                                                                                                                              
   17 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 netns                                                                                                                                  
   18 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 perf                                                                                                                                   
   19 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.10 khungtaskd                                                                                                                             
   20 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 writeback                                                                                                                              
   21 root      25   5       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ksmd                                                                                                                                   
   22 root      39  19       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:05.73 khugepaged                                                                                                                             
   23 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 crypto                                                                                                                                 
   24 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kintegrityd                                                                                                                            
   25 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset                                                                                                                                 
   26 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kblockd                                                                                                                                
   27 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ata_sff                                                                                                                                
   28 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 md                                                                                                                                     
   29 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 devfreq_wq                                                                                                                             
   34 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kswapd0                                                                                                                                
   35 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 vmstat                                                                                                                                 
   36 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 fsnotify_mark                                                                                                                          
   37 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ecryptfs-kthrea                                                                                                                        
   53 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kthrotld                                                                                                                               
   54 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 acpi_thermal_pm                                                                                                                        
   55 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 vballoon                                                                                                                               
   56 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset                                                                                                                                 
   57 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset                                                                                                                                 
   58 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset                                                                                                                                 
   59 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bioset
```

here are a few pastes of `top -d 30` as its updating:

1. https://pastebin.com/8TNUg2xh
2. https://pastebin.com/E0CS3bLH
3. https://pastebin.com/T5J3UHJv
4. https://pastebin.com/MUPSR7q5
5. https://pastebin.com/RqTJLQE8

Comment: the summary lines in top will tell you what the server is mostly doing...`%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st`  do `top -d 30` so it refreshes slow enough to copy the top 20 lines

Comment: We're currently seeing the exact same issue on DigitalOcean. Would mean a lot if you could update with the steps you took to resolve this. Thanks!!!

Comment: @ErikPerik I had a pretty simple setup on DO at the time (no load balancers, just a single server running apache) so I ended up just taking all my data off the server, spinning up a new droplet, and voila -- everything was much faster after reinstalling our apps on a new server. I'm not sure why this worked, perhaps it's because changing servers forces ip addresses/dns/system configs to be flushed/reset, but I still have no idea what the specific problem was. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

I don't think it's related to the certificate, as a raw openssl connection takes up to 5 seconds  to connect, and then returns very quickly; https://hastebin.com/ejipapehux.rb

```
$ openssl s_client -connect environmentaldashboard.org:443  -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.trust.crt   | ts -s "%.S"
depth=0 C = US, ST = Ohio, L = Oberlin, O = Environmental Dashboard, CN = 104.131.103.232
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = Ohio, L = Oberlin, O = Environmental Dashboard, CN = 104.131.103.232
verify return:1
05.800695 CONNECTED(00000003)
05.800967 ---
05.801019 Certificate chain
05.801060  0 s:/C=US/ST=Ohio/L=Oberlin/O=Environmental Dashboard/CN=104.131.103.232
```

it's taking 5 or more seconds to respond to the initial `Hello`, so I'd inspect the server and see what is going on;

[image]

Do you have console access to the machine?

Comment: Admittedly the page is fairly large at 2.1MB but what I'm concerned about is that `time_appconnect`, `time_pretransfer`, and `time_starttransfer` are all very high when accessing the HTTPS version *but not* the HTTP version, suggesting there is a network issue related to the SSL, not something related to the website itself. When I load the website in Chrome it spends most of the time "establishing secure connection," which would also indicate a network issue with the SSL.

Comment: Yeah, there is definitely a problem, intermittently it's very slow indeed.

Comment: Yeah, results are very inconsistent -- usually the first load will take ~10 seconds but then subsequent loads will take under a second, presumably because the browser has cached whatever network settings are causing the slowness. I have a 1 line [PHP script](https://environmentaldashboard.org/test2) that just `<?php echo time(); ?>`. This page loads slowly on the first load but very fast on subsequent loads.

Comment: Yes, I have SSH access. What configuration files are relevant here? I've looked through the syslog but don't see anything obvious wrong there. btw when I try `openssl s_client -connect environmentaldashboard.org:443` it prints `CONNECTED(00000005)` immediately but the rest of the response comes 10-15 seconds later. On the other hand, `openssl s_client -connect google.com:443` prints out everything immediately.

Comment: Check the basic stuff first, check the system clock is correct, DNS can resolve addresses. `free -h` for available memory, `top` to see whether the system is generally stuck on I/O, or idle... `/var/log/apache2/error.log` for anything. also check the syslog or `journalctl -xef` paste the output into your question

Comment: CPU and memory are never above 50%, DNS can resolve addresses, `htop` looks normal, etc. I will paste the output of `tail -n50 /var/log/apache2/error.log` and `journalctl -xef` into the question.

Comment: I pasted the output of those commands but there's too much useless stuff going on to see much. Are there things I can `grep` for?